# Do I need to shut off the gas to my water heater, when I shut off the cold water intake to fix a leaking hot water faucet in my basement sink?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, faucet

I need to replace a leaking hot water faucet in my basement laundry sink. To do this I need to shut of the hot water going into that faucet. The only option I see is to turn off the cold water intake to the water heater and then let one or more hot water taps drain the hot water from the tank. So when I do this (shut off the cold water to the water heater) - Do I need to shut off the gas to my water heater, when I shut off the cold water intake to fix a leaking hot water faucet in my basement sink?

Comment: Usually there is a valve below the sink which allows you to turn off the cold and hot water supplies to the sink separately.

Comment: And if there isn't a shutoff at the sink, now would be a good time to install one for next time.

Comment: I could be wrong: I believe if you turn off the cold intake to the hot water the vacuum is created and no hot will come out.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bad idea to turn off the gas while you work on your water system as the water level inside the tank may become unacceptably low, or pressures to high if you shut all the valves off; triggering the T&P relief valve.

You **must** turn off the gas or power if you have to drain the entire system and the tank.